# Change div to textarea with TinyMCE using jQuery replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to change some text with tinyMCE editor using jQuery replaceWith(), It's no problem with replaceWith() function itself, but I don't know how to implement  tinyMCE editor to new textarea.

```
<div id="div">Some text</div>
```

When edit button clicked, will change to

```
<textarea id="new">Some text</textarea> (with tinyMCE editor)
```

I tried 2 ways,

**1. Init tinymce selector before replacing - not working**

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#input_insertComment",
```

**2. - useing tinymce instance(?) - not working**

```
$('#div').replaceWith("<textarea id=new>some text</textarea>");
tinymce.initMCEexact("#new");
```

Both the editor aren't implemented. How can I do that?

(At the same page, I have tinymce editor for another textarea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `tinymce.init()` it will only impact items that exist in the DOM when you call `init()`.  If you are adding elements to the page later the `init()` call won't then replace them with TinyMCE.

The sequence you want is...

1. Add the textarea to the DOM
2. Call `tinymce.init()` and use the `selector` option in the init to target the textarea that you just added to the page.

I am not aware of `tinymce.initMCEexact()` as an actual API call that was ever part of TinyMCE - its not part of TinyMCE 4 for sure.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that shows how this might work:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/3qfaab